# Performance according to the number of controls within the CollectionView

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

we are developing with xamarin.forms.

Currently, we are creating a layout in which a list of cards comes out and there is a list (different number for each card) in that card.

When I actually bound the data and checked it on the device, the speed was too slow and there was a scrolling cycle.

The number of cards is about 10-20, and the number of cards inside is similar to 10-20.

In addition, there are stack layouts in the list and 4~5 controls such as label and boxview exist.

​

As a result, each card has about 40 to 200 controls.
For the entire list, you will have 400 to 2000 units.

The card consists of CollectionView, and the list inside the card is flexLayout.

​

I looked at the profiling and it seems that only the cards that appear on the screen when scrolling are created when collectionView is displayed on the screen, and when one card is created, about 400 objects (controls) are created, memory becomes high and GC works.

​

As a result, GC turns around and shows how the UI stumbles. Also, cards that are far from the screen disappear again, so when I scroll again, it slows down again.

​

Because of this phenomenon, I get stuck in every scroll, is there any good solution?

​

In addition, it seems difficult to reduce the number of controls in the current situation.

We will also see four to six cards per screen.

```
        <CollectionView 
            Margin="10">
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="***">
                    <StackLayout
                        Margin="0, 10, 0, 10"
                        CompressedLayout.IsHeadless="True">
                        <Grid
                            Margin="0, 10, 0, 10"
                            >
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Label 
                                Grid.Column="0"
                                Margin="0, 20, 0, 0"
                                FontSize="Small">
                            <FlexLayout
                                Grid.Row="0"
                                Grid.Column="1"
                                Wrap="Wrap"
                                VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                                HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                >
                                <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate x:DataType="***">
                                        <StackLayout
                                            x:DataType="***" 
                                            Orientation="Vertical"
                                            CompressedLayout.IsHeadless="True"
                                            Padding="4">
                                            <Label 
                                                FontSize="Micro" 
                                                TextColor="#20B78C"
                                                HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                                Margin="0, 0, 0, -8"/>
                                            <BoxView 
                                                Margin="0, 2, 0, 0"
                                                HeightRequest="1"
                                                BackgroundColor="#CBE5CC" />
                                            <Label 
                                                Margin="0, -5, 0, 0"
                                                FontSize="Medium"
                                                HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
                                        </StackLayout>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                            </FlexLayout>
                        </Grid>
                    </StackLayout>
                </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <CollectionView.Footer>
            <StackLayout 
                Orientation="Horizontal"
                HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                <Button 
                    Text="**"
                    HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"/>
                <Button 
                    Text="**"/>
            </StackLayout>
        </CollectionView.Footer>
    </CollectionView>
```

Comment: What is your question?  You have not posted any code so it is impossible to give you any specific suggestions.

Comment: @Jason All right, I'll add the code, I'm out of the item. My problem is that there's a lag when scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

To get smooth scrolling of items in a `CollectionView`:

---

Make each card a fixed height:

```
<CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:DataType="***">
        <StackLayout HeightRequest="200" ...
```

Similarly, specify fixed height on items in the `FlexLayout`:

```
    <StackLayout HeightRequest="40" ...
```

The next step up in complexity, while maintaining layout performance for smooth scrolling, is to use a DataTemplateSelector, to select between several DataTemplates, each of which has a HeightRequest. So layout doesn't have to dynamically calculate height, but several different heights are allowed.

If having hardcoded HeightRequests do not work for your design, then it may be necessary to write a custom layout class, with code to efficiently perform the layout. (Beyond the scope of this answer.)

---

Use as few `Layout` classes as possible.

Current design has `StackLayout`, `Grid`, and `FlexLayout`.

The last two are essential to the design, but try to eliminate `StackLayout`.

If can remove it, then put the `CompressedLayout.IsHeadless="True"` on Grid. (Unless Grid uses any visual features that aren't compatible with `IsHeadless`.)

NOTE: This is a minor optimization compared to the first one. If cards have fixed height, removing StackLayout will probably have no noticeable effect on performance. I just mentioned this as a general principle to be aware of - sometimes additional `Layout` classes are the cause of slowdown.